# How to properly modify the sudoers file to create a launcher in order to shutdown the system?

Tags: launcher, system, command-line

I did it adding the following line,  but doesn't work (at least in my case):

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/sbin/shutdown -h now
```

then making a launcher in the desktop with the following instruction:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

When I tried it, keeps asking me the password. What am I doing wrong?

PS:
I'm using visudo

Comment: Try executing `sudo /sbin/shutdown -h now` (note the full path just like in `/etc/sudoers`).

Comment: I tried just now, but keeps asking the password. I'm using Lucid Lynx and adding the line in the following section of the sudoers file:

#User privilege specification

Comment: Just to be sure, you put your real user name in that line (in place of `username`)? Lines starting with `#` are comments and are irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, I'm putting my real username.  before ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/sbin/shutdown -h now

About the section of the sudoers file, I know that # are comments but, Can I add the line in any section of the file and it should work?

Comment: The `sudoers` file does not have sections, it is just a list of lines.

Comment: But that reminds me that order is important. The last matching line is used, whatever it says. So put this line as the last on in the file.

Comment: Works just like a charm. Thanks for your knowledge I won't forget this anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of lines in `/etc/sudoers` is important.

The man page says:

```
   When multiple entries match for a user, they are applied in order.  Where there are
   multiple matches, the last match is used (which is not necessarily the most specific
   match).
```

So, if you have the following usual line in your `/etc/sudoers` file

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

and your user is part of the `admin` group, you need to put the line in your question behind that line. Otherwise it will never be used, because the line for `%admin` will always match instead.

In general, put the most specific lines (like those for single users and commands) at the end of the file.